# Few Projectproperty and Listproperty fields returning empty values (CrossListQueryInfo)

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I am running a CrossListQueryInfo and the ViewFields for the CAML includes

```
  <ProjectProperty Name="Title"/>
<ProjectProperty Name="Url"/>
<ListProperty Name="Title"/>
<ListProperty Name="DefaultViewUrl"/>
```

I am getting empty values for Url and DefaultViewUrl, although it is returning Titles correctly. Is this some limitation or I am missing something?

Comment: The CrossListQueryInfo is badly depends on context. It will helpful if you describe more on how your calling it. Share some code.